# Cast Result<Box<Struct>> to Result<<Box<dyn Trait>>>

Tags: rust, traits

I have a struct `MyStruct` that implements the trait `MyTrait`.

How I can map `Result<Box<MyStruct>>` to get `Result<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` without passing to `map()` an explicit lambda with the return type?

The code

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct;

trait MyTrait {}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError;

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, MyError>;

fn foo(_: &mut dyn MyTrait) {}

fn main() {
    let res: Result<MyStruct> = Ok(MyStruct {});
    let res: Result<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = res.map(Box::new);
    // let res: Result<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = res.map(|x| -> Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    //     Box::new(x) //too verbose
    // });
    foo(res.unwrap().as_mut());
}
```

causes the compile error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:41
   |
17 |     let res: Result<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = res.map(Box::new);
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait MyTrait, found struct `MyStruct`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<std::boxed::Box<dyn MyTrait>, _>`
              found type `std::result::Result<std::boxed::Box<MyStruct>, _>`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=58b274e0c8296a86cc42d6d23c3e67d3)